# oksetState functions is not updated in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I am rendering the multiple forms upon the selection of no of users done through a dropdown button,
where I am generating helper text and userdata state for those generated users dynamically .

this is where I initialize the state objects

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(0);
const [registrationData,setRegistrationData]=React.useState([]);
const [error,setError]=React.useState({});
const [registrations]=React.useState([]);
const [campaign, setCampaign] = React.useState({});
```

THis is the handling of the drop-down button:

```
const handleMenuItemClick=(event, index)=>{
        console.log("CLicked "+(index+1))
        setSelectedIndex(index);
        setAnchorEl(null); 
};
```

And this is the where the states are generated dynamically using the useEffect:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        setCampaign(prevCampaign => ({
            ...prevCampaign,
            ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
                [i]: {
                    sms_campaign: false,
                    email_campaign: false,
                }
            })))
        }));
        setError(prevError => ({
            ...prevError,
            ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
                [i]: {
                   uscf_id:"",
                   first_name:"",
                   middle_name:"",
                   last_name:"",
                   city:"",
                   state:"",
                   country:"",
                   phone_number:"",
                   email_id:"",
                }
            })))
        }));
        setRegistrationData(prevReg => ({
            ...prevReg,
            ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
                [i]: {
                uscf_id:"",
                first_name:"",
                middle_name:"",
                last_name:"",
                sections:"",
                city:"",
                state:"",
                country:"",
                phone_code:"",
                phone_number:"",
                email_id:"",
                sms:"",
                email:""
            }
            })))
        }));
        },[selectedIndex])
```

This is where I render cards:

```
registrations.filter((index)=>{
                    return (index<selectedIndex);
                }).map((registration,index)=>{
                    return(
                        <Card className={classes.cardLayout}>
                            <Avatar className={classes.icon}>
                                {index+1}
                            </Avatar>
                            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                            <TextField

                                id="outlined-error-helper-text"
                                label="ID"
                                name="id"
                                placeholder="Enter ID"
                                variant="outlined"
                                helperText={error[index].id}
                                error={(error[index].id===null||error[index].d==="")?false:true}
                                onChange={(event)=>updateUserdata(event,index)}
                                className={classes.textField}
                            />
.....
.....
```

This is where the dropdown button is handled:

```
 <Button
                    aria-controls="simple-menu" 
                    aria-haspopup="true" 
                    variant="outlined" 
                    color="inherit"  
                    label="registrations"
                    style={{marginLeft:20}}
                    endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon/>}
                    onClick={(event)=>handleClick(event)}
                    >
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="inherit">
                    //here , I have mentioned selectedIndex+1 to just show 1 instead of 0
                        {selectedIndex+1}
                    </Typography>
                    </Button>
                        <Menu
                            id="simple-menu"
                            anchorEl={anchorEl}
                            keepMounted    
                            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                            onClose={handleClose}
                        >
                        {[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map((option, index) => (
                            <MenuItem                                       
                                style={{paddingRight:85}}
                                key={option}
                                name="no_of_registrations"
                                selected={(index === selectedIndex)}
                                onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
                            >
                                {option}
                            </MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </Menu>
```

I also have form validation which I call when the user clicks on the register button , to perform the checks on fields and now only the selectedIndex card fields are setting the error text previous remaining cards are not set with the error text.

```
const formValidation=()=>{
        console.log("entered Form validation function")
        let valid=true;
        for(var i=0;i<selectedIndex;i++){
            if(registrationData[i].id===""){
                setError((error)=>({...error,[i]:{...error[i],id:"required" }}))
                valid=false
            }else {
                if(!(registrationData[i].id).match(/^[0-9]+$/)||([registrationData[i].id].length!==10)){
                    setError((error)=>({...error,[i]:{...error[i],id:"required" }}))
                    valid=false
                }else{
                    setError((error)=>({...error,[i]:{...error[i],id:"required" }}))
                }
            }
....
```

Comment: yes, you can use several setState functions.

Comment: but the state is not updated after setting the state

Comment: why you think the state is not updated after setting the state. what's your evidence?

Comment: when I am rendering the helper text in each field , `helperText={error[index].first_name}
                                error={(error[index].first_name===null||error[index].first_name==="")?false:true}` this guves me an error saying undefined

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I started writing this as an answer, but I'm not sure it answers the question you're asking. It does point out a problem with your existing code, so if it helps: https://pastebin.com/sjUkXxZj

Comment: Also, a loop starting at `0` and going `<=selectedIndex` looks off. Usually loops starting at `0` go to `<` their upper bound, not `<=`. But I don't have enough context to say whether that's actually a problem above.

Comment: @RitteshP.V, I guess your loop does not reach to your desired setState. the problem comes from your code.

Comment: yea, I understand so what should I do now , I changed the looping part  but still the problem exists

Comment: Do you want to update all indexes before the selected index or just the selected index

Comment: I want to update the state values of error ,campaign,registrationData where are generated dynamically upon the selectedIndex. I am using a for loop to do it

Comment: Sure but my question is, do you really want to update all indexes less than selected state. Is that the purpose of for loop in your code

Comment: no I want all to have the same indexes , basically , each selectedIndex denotes the no of cards to generate and along with it the respective helper text and registration data

Comment: I have updated my question more code please have a look and answer please

Comment: @RitteshP.V Why are you commenting to yourself? If you want to reply to someone you have to use `@`

Comment: @HMR okay , I will make it a practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update your state only once and not within a for loop specially without using a state updater callback.

You can perform the update by returning the object values within each state updater by mapping over an array created of length equal to selectedIndex

```js
useEffect(()=>{
    setCampaign(prevCampaign => ({
        ...prevCampaign,
        ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
            [i]: {
                sms_campaign: false,
                email_campaign: false,
            }
        })))
    }));
    setError(prevError => ({
        ...prevError,
        ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
            [i]: {
               id:"",
               first_name:"",
               middle_name:"",
               last_name:"",
               city:"",
               state:"",
               country:"",
               phone_number:"",
               email_id:"",
            }
        })))
    }));
    setRegistrationData(prevReg => ({
        ...prevReg,
        ...Object.assign({}, ...[...new Array(10).keys()].map(i => ({
            [i]: {
            id:"",
            first_name:"",
            middle_name:"",
            last_name:"",
            sections:"",
            city:"",
            state:"",
            country:"",
            phone_code:"",
            phone_number:"",
            email_id:"",
            sms:"",
            email:""
        }
        })))
    }));
    },[selectedIndex])
```

Comment: I have updated the coede please refer and say my mistake , please

Comment: When you update in a loop with setState, the state values get overriden by your last update which is why you should use callback approach with state updater.. You code too will work if you use the callback method, however setting state once is a much better way

Comment: okay , I will try please stay online this is some important work for me

Comment: Yours answer kind of solved my issue , but the useEffect method of yours generates 10 objects , but I want that with respect to the selectedIndex and the my error text  is showing only for the selected index card and not for the remaining cards , I have updated the questions please check

Comment: In such a case you didn't need a map or a loop. Remove that part and it should work like you want it to

Comment: what about the error text issue ? when I am doing the formvalidation

Comment: Prbably you don't need a for loop there, although I am not sure what you are trying to do